# Use values from adjacent rows in different columns of a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

Table `mytable` in mysql has columns col1 and col2 with integer not null values. It also has a primary key `id`. After arranging the columns in a certain order, I need to calculate a certain sum from all the elements of columns `col1` and `col2`  as follows: For a given value in col2 in a given row, compare it with the value of col1 in the next row. Take the smaller of these two values and subtract from it the value of col1 in the row where the value of col2 was taken; for the last row just subtract from the value in col2 the value in col1 in that row. Get the sum of all these differences.

I have the following solution which seems to work but might disturb where the user lacks privileges to create tables or alter the table structure. It would require checking existence of a table and some columns before they are created, besides needing to clean up after running,  to remove the columns added.

```
alter table mytable  add my_id int(5) not null;
alter table mytable add col3 int(7) not null;

SET @count = 0;
UPDATE mytable  SET my_id = @count:= @count + 1;

create temporary table mytable2 as select my_id, col1 from mytable  limit 1, 99999;
update mytable a join mytable2 b on a.my_id = (b.my_id - 1) set a.col3 = b.col1;

update mytable set col3 = col2 order by my_id desc limit 1;

select sum(LEAST(col2,col3) - col1) from mytable;
```

The Question: What would be a better way of getting the desired sum described above?

Here is some sample data:

```
           id   col1    col2
         --------------------
           11   609     618
           42   620     628
           23   624     630
           34   627     637

Required Sum: (618-609) + (624-620) + (627-624) + (637-627) = 26
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the "next row".  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I have included sample data and edited the question to indicate that the data is to be taken as ordered.